# Dynamic Binding in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, dynamic, binding

Why does the derived class have to declare its methods as virtual for dynamic binding to work even though the methods of the base class are declared virtual?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't have to. If a method is declared virtual in a base class, overriding it in a derived class makes the overriding function virtual as well, even if the `virtual` keyword is not used.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't.

```
class Base
{
    virtual void foo() {}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    void foo() {}
}
```

in this code `foo()` is still virtual in the `Derived` class even though it isn't declared as such.

Answer (score 2):

Is it? The following code produces the expected output B::f1() (compiled using VS2008):

```
class A
{
public:

    virtual ~A(){}
      virtual void f1()
      {
        std::cout<<"A::f1()\n";
      }

        virtual void f2()
      {
        std::cout<<"A::f2()\n";
      }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
       void f1()
      {
        std::cout<<"B::f1()\n";
      }

         void f2()
      {
        std::cout<<"B::f2()\n";
      }
};


int  main()
{
    B b;
    A* p = &b;
    p->f1();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To quote the C++ Standard (10.3.2):

> If a virtual member function `vf` is declared in a class `Base` and in a class `Derived`, derived directly or indirectly from `Base`, a member function `vf` with the same name and same parameter list as `Base::vf` is declared, then `Derived::vf` is also virtual (whether or not it is so declared) and it *overrides* `Base::vf`.

You can sum up this with: "once virtual, always virtual". However, you can still add the `virtual` modifier to the overriding member functions in order to make it clear for the user that the class is polymorphic.

Answer (score 0):

One need not to.
But i prefer using virtual in the derived class functions too as it will make the dynamic binding associated with those function more clear while reading the code.